# How can I fetch a localhost resource from the browser console and not get the Content Security Policy violation error?

Tags: google-chrome, fetch, localhost, content-security-policy

I have the most trivial local http server which is wired to serve a single file from localhost. I can navigate to the resource from the browser just fine, but I need to be able to fetch the resource using the `fetch` web api from the browser console and that just does not work **unless the console is from exactly the same origin**.

Please, observe:

The resource is live:

```
C:\> (Invoke-WebRequest http://localhost:49152/C:/temp/events/62.0.0.32712-0515-834-4.build.Main_events.json).StatusCode
200
C:\>
```

When the console is from the same origin:
[image]

Otherwise:
[image]

I understand I can ignore the first error - the one mentioning http://127.0.0.1:9001. So my problem is the second error:

```
Refused to connect to 'http://localhost:49152/C:/temp/events/62.0.0.32712-0515-834-4.build.Main_events.json' because it violates the document's Content Security Policy.
```

So far I failed to figure out how to fix it. It seems to be the classical CORS issue, but when running `fetch` the browser does not issue any preflight OPTIONS request. I know this because I am running Fiddler. It shows the `GET` request from the same origin, but absolutely no request from another origin.

The original `fetch` code that I am trying to make work is this:

```
    const request = fetch(url)
                        .then(response => response.blob())
                        .then(blob => {
                          globals.dispatch(Actions.openTraceFromFile({
                            file: new File([blob], fileName),
                          }));
                        })
                        .catch(e => alert(`Could not load local trace ${e}`));
```

It comes from https://www.ui.perfetto.dev/ which I am trying to make load my trace file non interactively.

(This question is related to [How to open a chrome trace file with ui.perfetto.dev non interactively?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70524472/how-to-open-a-chrome-trace-file-with-ui-perfetto-dev-non-interactively) and [How can I open chrome browser with disabled document's content security policy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70535318/how-can-i-open-chrome-browser-with-disabled-documents-content-security-policy))

I tried running chrome with the `--disable-web-security` flag, which is supposed to disable CORS validation (to the best of my understanding of this flag). To no avail.

Is there anything I can do to make it work?

---

The web server source code:

```
function NavigateToFile(
    [Parameter(Mandatory)][ValidateScript({ Test-Path $_ -PathType Leaf })]$FilePath,
    [scriptblock]$Action
)
{
    $port = Get-OpenTcpPort
    $http = [Net.HttpListener]::new()
    $http.Prefixes.Add("http://localhost:$Port/")
    $http.Start()

    $FilePath = (Get-Item $FilePath).FullName.Replace('\', '/')
    $ExpectedUrl = "$($http.Prefixes)$FilePath"
    $ExpectedUrl | ForEach-Object $Action

    try
    {
        $run = $true
        while ($http.IsListening -and $run)
        {
            $context = $http.GetContext()
            Write-Host "$($context.Request.HttpMethod) $($context.Request.Url)"
            if ($context.Request.HttpMethod -eq 'GET')
            {
                if ($context.Request.Url -eq $ExpectedUrl)
                {
                    $buffer = [IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($FilePath)
                }
                else
                {
                    $buffer = [Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes("Terminated")
                    $run = $false
                }
                $context.Response.ContentLength64 = $buffer.Length
                $context.Response.OutputStream.Write($buffer, 0, $buffer.Length)
                $context.Response.OutputStream.Close()
            }
        } 
    }
    finally
    {
        $http.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not CORS, it's the Content Security Policy, defined here:

https://github.com/google/perfetto/blob/master/ui/src/frontend/index.ts#L127

It supports only fetch from localhost:9001 to reduce the attack surface.

If you make your webserver listen on port 9001 rather than a random port, the error should go away.